# How to log MassTransit CorrelationId with Serilog?

Tags: masstransit, serilog

I am using MassTransit 3.5.7. I add the correlation ids before starting the bus:

```
MessageCorrelation.UseCorrelationId<ICustomerRegistered>(x => x.CustomerGuid);
MessageCorrelation.UseCorrelationId<ICustomerUpdated>(x => x.Customer.Guid);
MessageCorrelation.UseCorrelationId<IOrderPaid>(x => x.OrderGuid);
MessageCorrelation.UseCorrelationId<IOrderPaymentAuthorized>(x => x.OrderGuid);
MessageCorrelation.UseCorrelationId<IOrderPlaced>(x => x.Order.OrderGuid);
MessageCorrelation.UseCorrelationId<IOrderRefunded>(x => x.OrderGuid);
```

I use Serliog 2.5.0 for logging:

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(serviceBus =>
{
    serviceBus.UseSerilog();
    ...
}
```

I can see that the CorrelationId is added to the message headers, but it's not added as a custom property to the logs.

What do I need to do in order to log the CorrelationId for all logged messages?

**UPDATE:**

I implemented a Serilog enricher and a MassTransit custom middleware like [here](https://gist.github.com/gertjvr/3ee7674f359942d964952dfd80753e00), but the correlation id is only logged in the received (consumed) messages. It is not logged when publishing a message. Does anyone know **how can I log the correlation id when publishing a message?**

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Mass Transit. But I looked through their [Serilog integration code](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/develop/src/Loggers/MassTransit.SerilogIntegration) and it didn't seem to provide any method of capturing the correlation ID. Perhaps you could write some [custom middleware](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/middleware/custom.html) that grabs the correlation ID and uses [enrichment](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment) to add the correlation ID to the logged event?

Comment: Ah, it appears someone has [done just that](https://gist.github.com/gertjvr/3ee7674f359942d964952dfd80753e00).

Comment: @mason, thanks for the help. I found that gist and tried to implement it, but I think he is trying to solve a different problem. He is not getting the CorrelationId set in MassTransit, but he is setting a custom Guid that comes from the http request (actually Guid.NewGuid() in the code). I need to use the CorrelationId set in MassTransit.

Comment: Hmm .. after looking some more at the code, I think it might be what I need. I will try to implement it again tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: @mason I tried to implement the code from the gist, but the correlation id is added only to the consumed messages. It is not added to the published messages. I called the UseSeriLogEnricher method on the service bus configuration, not only on the receive endpoint, but I still get the correlation id only on the consumed messages. Any ideas?

Comment: It only calls `UseSeriLogEnricher` on the receive endpoint. You might need to see if there's something similar you can do for the publishing part.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and I called `UseSeriLogEnricher` on the entire service bus configuration which contains all receive endpoints and I think should also contain the publishers, but it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

You can Achieve this quite easily, and you are correct, it's with your own middleware.

I did that just that in this [example](https://github.com/maldworth/StarterKit-MassTransit/blob/master/StarterKit.Module/Middlewares/LoggerContextFilter.cs). Now I am using LibLog (hence you will see LogProvider). But if you are referencing SeriLog directly, then you can simply do [LogContext.PushProperty(...)](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment), and you will still get the same effect

Comment: I was able to log the correlation id for the received messages, but not for the messages published. Any idea on how I can achieve that?

Comment: You can use Audit functionality.
You can see it here: https://github.com/maldworth/StarterKit-MassTransit/blob/master/StarterKit.Service/Middlewares/SerilogMessageAuditStore.cs

and I register it https://github.com/maldworth/StarterKit-MassTransit/blob/27e26b48c1a3edd4e455ebf5558c5fa6ec9eb556/StarterKit.Module/MyService.cs#L31

You can read more about Audit here: http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/audit/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a custom masstransit filter. 
if you set up a filter

```
cfg.ConfigureSend(c => c.UseSendFilter(new YourSendFilter()));
```

or for publish

```
cfg.ConfigurePublish(c => c.UseSendFilter(new YourSendFilter()));
```