# Passing http RequestId to MassTransit Consumers

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I read all articles and forums for finding that, how to pass my http "Request-Id" to MassTarnsit Consumers.
all samples([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917714/how-to-log-masstransit-correlationid-with-serilog), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285341/rabbitmq-conversationid-vs-correlationid-which-is-the-more-appropriate-for-t), and [this](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/942)) sent a new GUID. but this way don't suitable for my case.

althought, I have been passed my "Request-Id" to Consumers, with this follow code:

```
       var reqId = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Request-Id"].FirstOrDefault();
        await _publishEndpoint.Publish(new MyMessageContract
        {
            CallBackUrl = "CallBackUrl",
            ApiToken = "ApiToken1"
        }, ctx => ctx.CorrelationId = Guid.Parse(reqId));
```

but this block code don't satisfy me! because of I have to pass my http "Request-Id" in each publishing contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at the [scoped filter](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ScopedFilters) sample, which uses middleware filters on publish, send, and consume to carry values from the HttpContext to the consumer.

Comment: @thanks a lot. it's seems so good for my case. but another issue!: when set  CorrelationId into header in 'publish filter' with this code: context.Headers.Set("CorrelationId", Guid.Parse(mycorrelationId));... then  I got this exception: "masstransit The message was not confirmed: Value of type 'Guid' cannot appear as table value"

Comment: For CorrelationId, you should use the built-in `context.CorrelationId = Guid.Parse(...)` instead of setting your own header value.

Comment: yes!. thanks a lot. you saved a part of my day.